# GROUP BY using parameters in SQL

Tags: sql, parameters, group-by, subtotal

I am trying to somehow group a report based on a drop-down list of parameters that is pre-defined.  I want to be able to subtotal the Total Hours or Total Pay of my report based on Department or JobCode. I have created the parameters and have no problem with that, I just am not sure if it's possible to use those parameters to call out a grouping command.  Below is the spirit of what I am wanting, but the GROUP BY clause doesn't work for me even without a parameter.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, Department, JobCode, PayRate, SUM(Hours) as "Total Hours", SUM(Pay) as "Total Pay"
FROM Employees
GROUP BY @GroupBy
```

I am truly a novice when it comes to SQL, so any help is very much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: If you are going to have dynamic GROUP BY, you'll need a dynamic SELECT.

Comment: It would help if you posted a table with some example data and two expected results according to "group by department" / "jobCode"

Answer (score 8):

The requirement is not 100% clear to me, but I imagine your after something like this:

```
select
  case when @groupBy = 'dept' then
       department else
       jobCode    end  dept_jobCode,
  sum(hours)
from employees
group by 
  case when @groupBy = 'dept' then
       department else
       jobCode    end;
```

To be tried with this setup:

```
create table employees (
  lastName   varchar(20),
  department varchar(20),
  jobCode    varchar(20),
  hours      number
);

insert into employees values ('Miller', 'Dept 1', 'A', 10);
insert into employees values ('Doe'   , 'Dept 1', 'A',  7);
insert into employees values ('Baker' , 'Dept 1', 'B',  4);

insert into employees values ('Sand'  , 'Dept 2', 'B',  6);
insert into employees values ('Stark' , 'Dept 2', 'B',  9);
insert into employees values ('Gild'  , 'Dept 2', 'A',  9);
```

Obviously, you want to set `@groupBy` to either `'dept'` or any other value.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding how `GROUP BY` works.

**GROUPING** is a way to aggregate many rows together.

If you return any fields not in the `GROUP BY`, you need to decide what to do with them.  You can't **NOT** do anything with them because you could have multiple values per group.  They must be either excluded or aggregated.

To aggregate them, you need to decide what function to use (`MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `AVG`, etc).

If you want to show many rows, say one per employee, but want to include some information about totals for that employee's department, you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT employeeid, <other unaggregated fields>
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT DepartmentID, SUM(Totalhours) as TotHours...etc
            FROM SomeOtherTable
            GROUP BY DepartmentID) as Sub
  ON Sub.DepartmentID = t.departmentID
```

There may be a way to do this dynamically but that is a pretty poor idea.

Answer (score 3):

`Group by` is simple really.

You have to list in `group by` every field that is included in the select statement and not fed to an aggregate function.

Which is why you can't have a variable `group by` with a fixed list of columns in `select`. (Well, you can in mysql, but it effectively applies virtual `any()` aggregate to them.)

Answer (score 3):

Any column you are selecting that are not used by one of the aggregate function (SUM, MIN, etc) needs to be listed in the `GROUP BY` clause.

For example,

```
SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, SUM(Hours) as "Total Hours"
FROM Employees
GROUP BY EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName
```

Good examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp