# OLEDB Named Parameters and Group By: "?" won't work

Tags: sql, excel, oledb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GROUP BY using parameters in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857090/group-by-using-parameters-in-sql)

Here is my SQL string for a OLEDB query of a .xlsx file

```
szSQL = "SELECT cawo_wo_id, wows_step_id, wows_description, wffj_cur_state_desc, cawo_wo_id & wows_step_id AS p5_id FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & sourceRange$ & "] WHERE [wows_description] like '%ECR%';"
```

I understand that named parameters are not supported by OLEDB, but why will it not work with a 'group by' using "?" as the parameter?

Like so:

```
szSQL = "SELECT cawo_wo_id, wows_step_id, wows_description, wffj_cur_state_desc, cawo_wo_id & wows_step_id AS p5_id FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & sourceRange$ & "] WHERE [wows_description] like '%ECR%' GROUP BY ?;"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm trying to remove duplicates from the field i cread p5_id.  That's why i'm using group by.

Comment: I dont know a SQL language that will let you use parameters in a group by in the way you are trying to do it.

Comment: @Stingyjack has already mentioned the invalid SQL.  However, regarding your question about the parameters, you'll have to use ODBC if you want to use ?-based parameters at all.  The alternative, if you can only connect via OLEDB, is to write VBA code to add/edit parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing that would group on the value that you send as the parameter value, and grouping on a literal value is not allowed.

If you want to group on different fields dynamically, you have to create the query dynamically, not put the field name in a parameter.